# Proving that merge sort time is increasing

Tags: algorithm

I have a question from the book:

> Prove that the number of compares used by merge sort is monotonically increasing `(C(N+1 > C(N)` for all `N>0)`.

I am really bad at proofs. Can anyone walk me through the steps on how to get this done?

Comment: Try it yourself and if you have a specific problem ask it on stackoverflow...

Comment: Please don't try to delete or remove your question. StackOverflow keeps all questions asked to allow people to see the answers given to you in future searches. If the question is deemed to be off-topic or not worth keeping we'll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The overall method for doing this is going to be, break up C(N) into C(M) and C(N-M) according to your merge sort algorithm. Do the same for C(N). There will either be overlap C(M) is the same for N and N+1 or there should be some way to breakup the new value (probably C(2*M)) into the old value (C(M)).